# Anonymous Processes

Tags: c++, process

Is it possible to, in Windows, create a sort of anonymous process? For instance, creating a process that shows up in task manager, which has a PID, etc. However, instead of starting it up with an EXE, you just give it an entry point address to a currently running process (sort of like a DLL) and it starts its own thread.

Is something like this possible? If so, how would one go about it?

EDIT: Also, preferably, the child process would die along with the parent process if the parent process returns or is terminated.

Comment: Why does it need to be a separate process? In other words, what's wrong with simply creating a new thread for this?

Comment: @CodyGray I need to be able to `AllocConsole` more than once and I wanted to see if I could hack-ishly do it without needing a separate file.

Comment: Ah, I see. Why, then, was that not the question you asked? Asking what you *really* want to know helps avoid the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @CodyGray True, but I wanted to keep it general if someone (or myself) wanted to use an anonymous process for something other than multiple console enumerations. There would be a lot of practical applications for something like this.